# Unsure why I'm getting IndexError: list index out of range when hardcoding for a whitespace in a decoding problem

Tags: python

As above, am learning Python3 and going through a message decoding problem. I have my code working for letters only, but when I introduce a string with a space (' ') my solution to try and hardcode the ASCII values of space and punctuation in to my nest `if` loop (within a `for` loop) I get the `IndexError: list index out of range`. I understand the error itself, but not how my code is triggering it.

This line of code is my attempt at creating a rule for space:

```
        if newnumberval == 32 + 107:
            outputmessage.append(' ')
```

This is my code so far:

```
import string
alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

#check each letter in message, take 10 from its alphanumeric value, add new val
# to outputlist
# if val - 10 is lower than 0, newval(negative) is taken from 26
# remove and store spaces and punctuation
#   solution1: hardcode spaces and punctuation values
#     i.e. if newnumberval(" ")= 22 then outputmessage.append(" ")
#   solution2: if letter not in alphabet, outputmessage.append(letter)

def decodemessage(message):
    outputmessage = []
    for letter in list(message):
        numberval = ord(letter) - 97
        newnumberval = numberval - 10
        if newnumberval == 32 + 107:
            outputmessage.append(' ')
        elif newnumberval < 0:
            newnumberval += 26
            outputmessage.append(alphabet[newnumberval])
        else:
            outputmessage.append(alphabet[newnumberval])
    return outputmessage
print(decodemessage('hello '))
```

Comment: What `letter` value do you expect to cause the `if` condition to be met? Why and how? How about the other possibilities? Talk me through the logic a step at a time: what do you expect the `numberval` result to be? The `newnumberval` result? "I get the IndexError: list index out of range. I understand the error itself, but not how my code is triggering it." Well, can you give an example of a single-character string that causes the error? When you try the process above, what do you conclude?

Comment: As far as I can tell from your notes, the problem appears to be that you are expecting 32 - 107 to be equal to 32 + 107. Either that, or you have in mind some expected value for the result of `ord(' ')` where I have no idea what it's based on.

Comment: Anyway, you should try using a search engine to look for easier ways to do this. It's easier if you know the name of what you're trying to do.

Comment: As an addendum to this question I have just thought of the possibility that using ASCII values as something to check against may have been the wrong train of thought to follow, is it 'better' programming to create my own library including punctuation and check through that instead? Not only am I getting stuck with coding syntax itself, but also the methods to follow when I'm planning out my own pseudocode!

Comment: The ASCII value of a space is 32, and in the for loop I take away 97 because the a value in ASCII is 97, and then take away 10 as that is the offset I am using in this Caesar Cipher decoder before I include an offset value as a variable in the function.

Comment: "is it 'better' programming to create my own library including punctuation and check through that instead?" All you need is the built-in `translate` and `maketrans` methods of the string type. Please try looking them up in the documentation. "

Comment: I know I could search up Caesar Cipher examples, but that wouldn't necessarily explain the problems in my own coding logic which is what I'm looking for to try and be a better programming student going forward.

Comment: The ASCII value of a space is 32, and in the for loop I take away 97 because the a value in ASCII is 97, and then take away 10 as that is the offset I am using in this Caesar Cipher decoder before I include an offset value as a variable in the function. Okay; so if you do that, the result should be `32 - 107`, yes? Notice how the code says `if newnumberval == 32 + 107:`? That's the code that's supposed to check whether `newnumberval` is equal to `32 - 107`? Do you see the problem?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I overlooked something that simple, thank you again for your help!

Comment: You'd better use: 
` if newnumberval + 107 == 32: `
Instead of:
` if newnumberval == 32 + 107:`

Comment: "but that wouldn't necessarily explain the problems in my own coding logic " Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Attention to detail is the second most important skill for a programmer, behind being able to give a clear statement of the problem.